# ggplot2 plot both x-axis and yaxis horizontally

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am polotting a value and its confidence interval for each test on certain data. x-axis data, y-axis tests.

It takes a lot of space in documentation, i would rather move the y-axis labels to top of the image and arrange the tiles horizontally.
[image: geom_tiles]

Here is the code that i was using

```
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x= DATA, 
                             #y=reorder(TEST, VALUE), 
                             fill = VALUE))+ 
  geom_tile(colour = 'White', aes(y=TEST, height = 1)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'salmon')+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='Tiles'))+
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "#4292C6", low = "#C6DBEF")+
  #coord_fixed(ratio = 0.1) +
  xlab("Data") + ylab('Test') + labs(color = 'AUROC') +  # 
  geom_text(aes(y=TEST,label = paste0(round(VALUE, 4),'\n','[',CI,']')), size = 4.7, fontface = 'bold') + 
  # ggtitle(name)+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle('Data vs Test') +
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1/5) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=18),
        axis.title=element_text(size=24),
        plot.title = element_text(size=26)) + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2,"line"), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=24),
        legend.text = element_text(size=16))
#legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction="horizontal")
plot(p)
```

what changes shall i make to arrange the tiles horizontally?
Edit:
[image]

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble imagining what the desired output is. Can you find an example of what you like the output to be or make drawing of what is should become?

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks for quick response. I added a dummy image, how i would like to have.

Comment: Doesn't replacing `y=TEST` by `y=1` give something close to what you like?

Comment: it did! thanks. how can add y labels on top of the plot? can you post it as an answer? I would accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `y=TEST` by `y=some_constant` to have all the tiles line up in a row. The x-axis can be placed at the top by setting `position = 'top'` in the scale. Simplified example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  DATA = factor(1:10),
  TEST = factor(1:10),
  VALUE = rnorm(10)
)

ggplot(df, aes(DATA, y = 1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = VALUE), colour = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(VALUE, 4))) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = 'top')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The solution worked for me and its perfect. I would like to have x-lables on the bottom and correspoding y lables on the top.

Comment: Discrete scales don't support secondary axes. To be clear, you cannot have the y-axis labels on the x-axis. You can make a discrete-like axis from a continuous scale and then use the secondary axis to label the top differently from the bottom.